# Add Integer Number to existing Values - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j.

I would like to add a integer number to values already existing in properties of several relationships that I call this way:

```
MATCH x=(()-[y]->(s:SOL{PRB:"Taking time"})) SET y.points=+2
```

But it doesn't add anything, just replace by 2 the value I want to incremente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this use

```
SET y.points = y.points + 2
```

From your original question it looks like you were trying to use the Addition Assignment operator which exists in lots of languages (e.g. python, type/javascript, C#, etc.). However, in cypher `+=` is a little different and is designed to do this in a way which allows you to add or update properties **to or on entire nodes or relationships** based on a mapping.

If you had a parameter like the below (copy this into the neo4j browser to create a param).

```
:param someMapping: {a:1, b:2}
```

The query below would create a property b on the node with value 2, and set the value of property a on that node to 1.

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel) WHERE n.a = 0
SET n+= $someMapping
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks - updated to make it more relevant / clearer!